# Using regular expression to find at least one repeating character in a string

Tags: java, regex, repeat

So I have a bonus task assigned and it asks to write a program which returns true if in a given string at least one character is repeated.

I am relatively new to regular expressions but to my knowledge this should work:

```
String input = "wool";
return input.matches(".*(.)/1+.*");
```

This should return true, because the '.*' at the beginning and the end express that there could be prefices or suffices. And the '(.)/1+' is a repeating pattern of any character.

As I said I'm relatively new to the regex stuff but I'm very interested in learning and understanding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost perfect, just `/` looks the wrong way around (should be `\`).

<strike>Also, you don't need `.*` for prefixes and suffixes - regexp will find a match anywhere in the string, so `(.)\1` suffices. This is not an error, just an optimisation (although in other cases it might, and does, make a difference).</strike>

One more issue is that backslashes are special characters in Java strings, so when you write a regexp in Java, you need to double up on backslashes. This gives you:

```
return input.matches(".*(.)\\1.*");
```

**EDIT:** I forgot, you don't need `+` because if something repeats 3 times, it also repeats 2 times, so you will find it just by searching for a two-character repetition. Again, not an error, just not needed here.

And Kita has a good point that your task is not well-defined, as it does not say whether you are looking for the repeating characters next to each other or anywhere in the string. My solution is for the adjacent characters; if you need the repetition anywhere, use his.

**EDIT2** after comments: Forgot the semantics of `.matches`. You guys are quite correct, edited appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for some reason removing the '.*' results in wrong answers. My guess is that the pattern has to fit exactly and not just partially. And "(.)\\1" is only matching to a string which repeats the same character twice. But doubling up the bachslashes solves the problem.

Comment: `input.matches("(.)\\1");` This won't work in Java, since `String.matches()` makes sure the regex matches the whole line. Search for existence of a pattern in a String can only be done by Matcher.find(). `input.matches(".*(.)\\1.*");` is what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

If the task "in a given string at least one character is repeated" includes the following pattern:

- `abcbd` (`b` is repeated)

then the regex pattern would be:

```
(.).*\1
```

This pattern assumes that other characters could be in between the repeating characters. Otherwise

`(.)\1`

will do.

Note that the task is to capture "at least one character is repeated", which means identifying a single occurrence is enough for the task, so `\1` does not have to have `+` quantifier.

The code:

```
return input.matches("(.).*\\1");
```

or

```
return input.matches("(.)\\1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution would be adding the  elements to hashset. Then checking the length of the string and the hashset.